# How to get just the field names from the given string in object format ( not using POJO ) from the following string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group

String is as follows :

```
"{
    account_number={
    type=long
    },
    firstname={
    type=text, fields={
    keyword={
    ignore_above=256, type=keyword
            }
        }
    },
    accountnumber={
    type=long
    },
    address={
    type=text, fields={
    keyword={
    ignore_above=256, type=keyword
            }
        }
    },
    gender={
    type=text, fields={
    keyword={
    ignore_above=256, type=keyword
            }
        }
    }
}"
```

I need to get only the names of these fields, i.e, account_number,firstname,accountnumber,address,gender. Pojo class won't work here since the content inside objects is not fixed. A reg ex may work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The example is not a valid JSON please check if its a string or a JSON

Comment: Hi @Hades : it's a string only. That is the issue. Some reg ex I need which can read only the field names account_number,firstname,accountnumber,address,gender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have converted ur string into JSON and then retrieved all the keys

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.json.JSONObject;


public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>();
        final String regex = "[a-z]\\w*";
        String string = "{\n"
             + "    account_number={\n"
             + "    type=long\n"
             + "    },\n"
             + "    firstname={\n"
             + "    type=text, fields={\n"
             + "    keyword={\n"
             + "    ignore_above=256, type=keyword\n"
             + "            }\n"
             + "        }\n"
             + "    },\n"
             + "    accountnumber={\n"
             + "    type=long\n"
             + "    },\n"
             + "    address={\n"
             + "    type=text, fields={\n"
             + "    keyword={\n"
             + "    ignore_above=256, type=keyword\n"
             + "            }\n"
             + "        }\n"
             + "    },\n"
             + "    gender={\n"
             + "    type=text, fields={\n"
             + "    keyword={\n"
             + "    ignore_above=256, type=keyword\n"
             + "            }\n"
             + "        }\n"
             + "    }\n"
             + "}";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
         while(matcher.find()) {
             String gp = matcher.group();
             keywords.add(gp);
         }
         for (String keyword : keywords) {
            string = string.replace(keyword, "\""+keyword+"\"");
        }
         string = string.replace("=", ":");
         System.out.println(string);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.keySet());
    }
}
```

output

```
[account_number, firstname, accountnumber, address, gender]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Hades. The problem with this solution is that "fileds" and "keywords" are not constants. It can be anything. Eg : 
{
       city : {
         type : text,
         fields : {
           raw : {
             type : keyword
           }
         }
       }
     }

Comment: @ishita07 check my updated answer. let me know if that works.

Comment: @ishita07 will u please upvote if u think its the best suited option for u question

Comment: yup done. Sorry missed to upvote yesterday. Just verified it :)
Thanks again ! :)